# Which lifecycle do I activate and deactivate constraints for Swift

Tags: swift3, constraints, lifecycle, xcode8

I'm struggling with when is the correct time to activate or deactivate constraints in the storyboard.

I've made an extremely simplified view controller showing this issue I'm having.

[image: view controller and tree]

Basically, there is UIView (the red box) and inside of that is the UIScrollView, and finally inside of that is the label containing the text. The UIScrollView is 15 away from all edges of the red UIView it is inside of. And the UILabel is 0 on all sides from the UIScrollView it is inside of. By default, I have a constraint from the bottom (called bottomConst) of the red UIView to the bottom of the super view. Meaning its always the same distance. And if nothing is changed it will look the following way on both a 4 inch and 4.7 inch screen. This is initiated as `isActive = true`.

[image]. [image]

As you can see, there is a large amount of blank white space on the 4.7 inch screen.

To fix this I've added a second constraint that controls the height of the red UIView (called heightConst) and this is initiated as `isActive = false`.

I use the code to check after `layoutIfNeeded()` if the bounds height of the UIScrollView is taller than the contentSize height of the UIScrollView. And if it is, then it deactivates the bottomConst and activates the heightConst. The problem is, instead of that happening. I end up getting a zero height UIScrollView and a UIView that 30 tall because of the 15 on top and bottom edge constraints.

[image]

But if I manually go in and switch them before running them, everything looks correct.

[image]

Here is the code I'm using. (see below)
I've tried placing the code in various places such as viewDidLoad, viewDidAppear, viewWillLayoutSubviews, viewDidLayoutSubviews. But none of them seem to work. I'm starting to wonder if I should be calling the LayoutIfNeeded() in a separate lifecycle but there are so many possibilities of how to do that I figured I'd come the people who always seem to know best. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var bottomConst: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet var heightConst: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


}

override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

    scrollView.setNeedsLayout()
    scrollView.layoutIfNeeded()

    let scrollHeight = scrollView.contentSize.height

    if (scrollHeight <= scrollView.bounds.height) {
        bottomConst.isActive = false

        heightConst.constant = scrollHeight + 30
        heightConst.isActive = true

        view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

Comment: You are doing it wrong. Make the hierarchy to be scrollview - view - label. Make the view to be the same size as the label. You are done, no constraint update needed.

Comment: I was thinking about what you were suggesting here. And I thought I'd point out the reason I did view > scrollview > label. I am using the view to be the color background and am rounding the corners. Otherwise I'd just have scrollview > label. But Even if I did your suggestion, I think I'd still have the same problem. I'd have to constrain the scrollview to a size with means I could end up with whitespace again, or a scrollview that is taller than my viewController. But thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I was able to find the answer to my problem. But its slightly complicated, and also may depend on how the view controller is setup.

For the case I show above the following code worked.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var bottomConst: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet var heightConst: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    view.setNeedsLayout()
    view.layoutIfNeeded()

    let scrollHeight = scrollView.contentSize.height

    if (scrollHeight <= scrollView.bounds.height) {
        bottomConst.isActive = false

        heightConst.constant = scrollHeight + 30
        heightConst.isActive = true
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

Turns out putting that code in `viewWillAppear` was where it needed to go, and marking the view as `setNeedsLayout` instead of the `scrollView`. But I also had another case that was very similar to the one I described above except the bottom constraint wasn't to the super view, it was to another UIView. In that case even with using the new code I still got a 0 height `scrollView`.

After doing some testing, I found that `heightConst` would remain true after I set it in the above code. But then it would go through the `viewWillLayoutSubviews` and `viewDidLayoutSubviews` one final time and in those it would become false again. My work around for that was to modify my code to the following.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var changeSize: Bool = false //Additional Code

@IBOutlet var bottomConst: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet var heightConst: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    view.setNeedsLayout()
    view.layoutIfNeeded()

    let scrollHeight = scrollView.contentSize.height

    if (scrollHeight <= scrollView.bounds.height) {
        changeSize = true //Addition Code
        bottomConst.isActive = false

        heightConst.constant = scrollHeight + 30
        heightConst.isActive = true
    }
}

//Addition Code
override function viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    if (changeSize == true && heightConst.isActive == false) {
        heightConst.isActive = true
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

But ultimately, the way I found the work around was to put a `print()` function in each lifecycle and see what it was reporting that constraint was. That way, I could see when it was going wrong. Hopefully this helps someone else in the future!